# Log4J do not writes to file, only to console

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I try write messages of my custom log level "BSHARING_LOG" to separate log file "bsharing.log". After start app, empty file 'bsharing.log' appears, but no messages in it. Both "test log message2" and "test log message" are on console. But not in file 'bsharing.log'.  Messages for standart levels writes to 'application.log'. What's wrong?

Part of my pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %p %m%n</Property>
        <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">logs</Property>
    </Properties>

    <CustomLevels>
        <CustomLevel name="BSHARING_LOG" intLevel="350" />
    </CustomLevels>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="appLog"
                fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/application.log"
                filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="19500KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="bsharingLogAppender"
                fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/bsharing.log"
                filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/bsharing-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="19500KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="ru.bozza.Sharing" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="appLog" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
        
        <Logger name="bsharinglogger" level="BSHARING_LOG" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="bsharingLogAppender" />
        </Logger>
        
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="appLog" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

class:

```
public class CustomSecurityFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        log.log(Level.forName("BSHARING_LOG", 350), "test log message2");
        log.log(Level.getLevel("BSHARING_LOG"), "test log message");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

If

```
<Root level="info">
   <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
   <AppenderRef ref="appLog" />
   <AppenderRef ref="bsharingLogAppender" />
</Root>
```

then logs writes to both files.
I can't understand, why my custom log messages appears only in console, but not in file 'bsharing.log'.

Comment: Instead of changing the title, can you write your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted?

Comment: If you are looking to log a specific aspect of your application to a separate log file, that is what markers are for (see [Markers documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html)). There is also [a filter for markers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MarkerFilter).

Comment: Hello. It is great that you want to share your solution with others! But please note that on this site solutions are meant to be posted as "answers" which are separated from problem description (the "question" section). This allows us to vote and comment on each answer separately from question. If you don't see area/form to post an answer (question authors usually don't need it so it may be hidden), you may need too click option like "answer your question" somewhere below your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posting an answer on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

I have solved it.

File log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %p %m%n</Property>
        <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">logs</Property>
    </Properties>

    <CustomLevels>
        <CustomLevel name="BSHARING_LOG" intLevel="350" />
    </CustomLevels>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="appLog"
                fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/application.log"
                filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
            <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="BSHARING_LOG" maxLevel="BSHARING_LOG" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="19500KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="bsharingLogAppender"
                fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/bsharing.log"
                filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/bsharing-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
            <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="BSHARING_LOG" maxLevel="BSHARING_LOG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="19500KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="appLog" />
            <AppenderRef ref="bsharingLogAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

See LevelRangeFilter params.